# Meaning: 好棋? (Good move?)

Tags: meaning

Seems like I'm not the only one confused about this, the country is coming up with slogans nobody understands.

Recently there have been a lot of signs put up with things like 中国前进 written on them, but the confusing part:

> 中国好棋!

Say what?

Is this the same as 好球? Just 棋 and not 球? Good move?

Comment: You mention "the country" without being specific. It could be China, Taiwan, Singapore...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,`好棋` means "a good move"; either in chess-style games or, by analogy, *anything* related to a contest of strategy (e.g. `普京毁了一步好棋`, "Putin screwed up a (previous) good move".)

The phrase in question, `中国好棋`, is a bit different. That originated from this poster,
where it is the *title* of a poem:

> 对弈小神童，尚在长成中。游戏无规矩，打闹是常情。但凡说故事，必须中国赢。落子成定局，欢呼轻高音。中国我爱你，年少正青春。

The character `好` has two meanings:

1. *adjective* "good"
2. *verb* "to like"

The latter meaning is the one intended in the phrase ``. So the phrase is saying "**China *likes* chess**" (or [Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28game%29) or generic board games). This can be inferred from the context provided by the poem, the visual emphasis on the `好` character, and also because a subject (`中国`) precedes it and an object `棋` follows it.

The other possible meaning for the phrase is something along the lines of a "*Chinese good move*". That doesn't fit the poster's context (though you can interpret it as a pun), but the phrase can be used with that meaning too. 
For instance, Chinese chess prodigy 侯逸凡 (Hou Yifan) has talked about the awakening Chinese dragon making a `中国好棋` on the chessboard of the world.

---

For reference, the poster:

[image]

Comment: Yes! “中国好棋” means we obey the rules to keep the world peaceful, make the whole human beings happy, honest, all in all, make everything in harmony and good.

Comment: Can I have sickbag, please?

Answer (score 2):

中国前进

- 中国: China
- 前进: move/march forward
- Possible usage: to cheer up the team of athlete representing China in an international sport competition

中国好棋

- 中国: China
- 好棋: "good chess"
- Possible usage: usually used in games of chess for expressing one's feeling that certain move is a "good move"

棋, 球

- 球: ball
- 棋: chess

好球

- Possible usage

  - The quality of the ball is good
  - Used in ball games like football to express one's feeling that an action performed by a football player is of high quality (e.g. scoring)

Answer (score 2):

In that case, it means GOOD MOVE. 好棋(hao3qi2). If you see something like 他好棋, it should be read as (hao4qi2), which means HE IS INTO CHESS.